# error LNK2005: xxx already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\something\LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker, msvcr100.dll

I'm using DCMTK library for reading Dicom files (Image format used in medical image processing.) I'm having a problem in compiling this DCMTK source code. DCMTK uses some additional external libraries (zlib, tiff, libpng, libxml2, libiconv). I know that all libraries should be generated with same Code Generation Options.

I've downloaded the compiled versions of these support libraries which are compiled with "Multithreaded DLL" runtime options (/MD). In each project of DCMTK source code I ensured that runtime options are "Multithreaded DLL" (/MD). But still I'm getting these errors:

```
Error   238 error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   239 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   240 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   241 error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   242 error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   243 error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   244 error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   245 error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   246 error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)   dcmp2pgm
Error   247 error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)   dcmp2pgm
Error   248 error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)   dcmp2pgm
Error   249 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   250 error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   251 error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   252 error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   253 error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   254 error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   255 error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmp2pgm
Error   256 error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   257 error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   258 error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   259 error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   260 error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(getenv.obj)   dcmp2pgm
Error   261 error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)  dcmp2pgm
Error   262 error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(strnicmp.obj) dcmp2pgm
Error   263 error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMT.lib(close.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   264 error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   265 error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   266 error LNK2005: _atol already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   267 error LNK2005: _strcspn already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strcspn.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   268 error LNK2005: __stricmp already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stricmp.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   269 error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   270 error LNK2005: __lseek already defined in LIBCMT.lib(lseek.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   271 error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMT.lib(read.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   272 error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMT.lib(write.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   273 error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMT.lib(open.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   274 error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmp2pgm
Error   278 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\Release\dcmp2pgm.exe 1   1   dcmp2pgm
Error   201 error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   202 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   203 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   204 error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   205 error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   206 error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   207 error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   208 error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   209 error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)   dcmprscp
Error   210 error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)   dcmprscp
Error   211 error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)   dcmprscp
Error   212 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   213 error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscp
Error   214 error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscp
Error   215 error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscp
Error   216 error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscp
Error   217 error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   218 error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmprscp
Error   219 error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) dcmprscp
Error   220 error LNK2005: __stricmp already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(stricmp.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   221 error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) dcmprscp
Error   222 error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   223 error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) dcmprscp
Error   224 error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(getenv.obj)   dcmprscp
Error   225 error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)  dcmprscp
Error   226 error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(strnicmp.obj) dcmprscp
Error   227 error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMT.lib(close.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   228 error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   229 error LNK2005: __lseek already defined in LIBCMT.lib(lseek.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   230 error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMT.lib(read.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   231 error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMT.lib(write.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   232 error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMT.lib(open.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   233 error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscp
Error   237 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\Release\dcmprscp.exe 1   1   dcmprscp
Error   160 error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   161 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   162 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   163 error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   164 error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   165 error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   166 error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   167 error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   168 error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)   dcmprscu
Error   169 error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)   dcmprscu
Error   170 error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)   dcmprscu
Error   171 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   172 error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscu
Error   173 error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscu
Error   174 error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscu
Error   175 error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmprscu
Error   176 error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   177 error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmprscu
Error   178 error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) dcmprscu
Error   179 error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) dcmprscu
Error   180 error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   181 error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) dcmprscu
Error   182 error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(getenv.obj)   dcmprscu
Error   183 error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)  dcmprscu
Error   184 error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(strnicmp.obj) dcmprscu
Error   185 error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMT.lib(close.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   186 error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   187 error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   188 error LNK2005: _atol already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   189 error LNK2005: _strcspn already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strcspn.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   190 error LNK2005: __stricmp already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stricmp.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   191 error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   192 error LNK2005: __lseek already defined in LIBCMT.lib(lseek.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   193 error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMT.lib(read.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   194 error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMT.lib(write.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   195 error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMT.lib(open.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   196 error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmprscu
Error   200 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\Release\dcmprscu.exe dcmprscu
Error   119 error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   120 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   121 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   122 error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   123 error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   124 error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   125 error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   126 error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   127 error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)   dcmpsprt
Error   128 error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)   dcmpsprt
Error   129 error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)   dcmpsprt
Error   130 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   131 error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   132 error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   133 error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   134 error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   135 error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   136 error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)    dcmpsprt
Error   137 error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   138 error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   139 error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   140 error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   141 error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(getenv.obj)   dcmpsprt
Error   142 error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)  dcmpsprt
Error   143 error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\LIBCMT.lib(strnicmp.obj) dcmpsprt
Error   144 error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMT.lib(close.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   145 error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   146 error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   147 error LNK2005: _atol already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   148 error LNK2005: _strcspn already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strcspn.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   149 error LNK2005: __stricmp already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stricmp.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   150 error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   151 error LNK2005: __lseek already defined in LIBCMT.lib(lseek.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   152 error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMT.lib(read.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   153 error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMT.lib(write.obj) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   154 error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMT.lib(open.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   155 error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) dcmpsprt
Error   159 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmpstat\apps\Release\dcmpsprt.exe 1   1   dcmpsprt
Error   61  error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)   dsr2html
Error   62  error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)   dsr2html
Error   63  error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)   dsr2html
Error   64  error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) dsr2html
Error   65  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) dsr2html
Error   66  error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) dsr2html
Error   67  error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) dsr2html
Error   68  error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) dsr2html
Error   69  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)  dsr2html
Error   70  error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)  dsr2html
Error   71  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)  dsr2html
Error   72  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)   dsr2html
Error   73  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)    dsr2html
Error   74  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)    dsr2html
Error   75  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)    dsr2html
Error   76  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)    dsr2html
Error   77  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)   dsr2html
Error   78  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)   dsr2html
Error   79  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)    dsr2html
Error   80  error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)    C:\dcmtk-3.5.4-src\CMakeBinaries\dcmsr\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj)    dsr2html
Error   81  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in
```

**EDIT:**

Observations:

1. There are conflicts only between LIBCMT.LIB & MSVCRT.LIB
2. These two LIB files doesn't exist at the locations shown in the errors.

**EDIT2:**

Yes, the problem was because some of the support libraries weren't built with /MD. So, I myself built all the support libraries with /MD and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You are mixing code that was compiled with /MD (use DLL version of CRT) with code that was compiled with /MT (use static CRT library).  That cannot work, all source code files must be compiled with the same setting.  Given that you use libraries that were pre-compiled with /MD, almost always the correct setting, you must compile your own code with this setting as well.

Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation, "Runtime Library" setting.

Beware that these libraries were probably compiled with an earlier version of the CRT, msvcr100.dll is quite new.  Not sure if that will cause trouble, you may have to prevent the linker from generating a manifest.  You must also make sure to deploy the DLLs you need to the target machine, including msvcr100.dll

Comment: I think you missed this point in my question: `In each project of DCMTK solution (source code) I ensured that runtime options are "Multithreaded DLL" (/MD). But still I'm getting these errors.` In the DCMTK solution (there are about 62 projects). For each project I've checked the Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting and it is /MD. Even after this I'm getting this error.

Comment: The linker is arguing with your statement, not me.  Beware of one of these "dcmtk" projects using a .lib itself that's compiled wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question. Do you have anything to comment about the 2nd point in my edit?

Comment: Well, the location of the LIBCMT in the error message is very strange, it doesn't belong there.  The only good guess I have it that the linker is actually picking up a pre-built version of a lib instead of the one you rebuilt yourself.

Comment: "pre-built version of a lib instead of the one you rebuilt yourself." I didn't build any LIBCMT / MSVCRT.Moreover important thing is there is no LIBCMT.LIB or MSVCRT.LIB at any of  those locations mentioned.

Comment: I know I'm kind of late to the party, but why does the compiler consider this a redifinition if you're using different CRT linkage styles? Why is this problem averted when using the same linkage style? Shouldn't it be considered a redefinition if, say, both projects have their own, statically linked version of CRT?

Comment: @ori - the linker, not the compiler.  It is told to link two .lib files (libcmt.lib and msvcrt.lib), both with the same definitions.  It refuses to favor one over the other.

Comment: @hans, yeah, I have a bad habit of calling the linker a compiler. Anyway, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Let me just say, this is one helpful answer.  I had the same problem with MPIR, because I built/used the static lib and tried to use it with my project instead of the dll lib - had no idea this could have been the problem

Answer (score 3):

Getting this error, I changed the

```
c/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library to Multi-threaded library (DLL) /MD
```

for both code project and associated Google Test project. This solved the issue.

Note: all components of the project must have the same definition in
c/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library.
Either DLL or not DLL, but identical.

Answer (score 2):

Some readers will have another issue and need this fix. read the links below. the same problem occured with visual studio 2015 with the advent of windows sdk 10 which brings up libucrt. ucrt is the windows implementation of  C Runtime (CRT) aka the posix runtime library.  You most likely have code that was ported from unix... Welcome to the drawback

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/148652/a-lnk2005-error-occurs-when-the-crt-library-and-mfc-libraries-are-linked-in-the-wrong-order-in-visual-c

https://github.com/lordmulder/libsndfile-MSVC/blob/master/src/sf_unistd.h

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2011-09/msg00224.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Answer (score 1):

If you VS solution contains several projects, select all of them in the right pane, and press "properties". Then go to C++ -> Code Generation and chose one Run Time library option for all of them