# How to change the C++ Runtime Library setting in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm absolutely new to Qt. I've made a program using C++ in Visual Studio 2010 in which I use the external library from Dcmtk. I now want to add a user interface to that program. In my original program I had to change the C++ `Runtime Library` in Code Generation setting in Visual Studio to `Multi-Threaded(/MT)` from `Multi-Threaded Debug DLL` otherwise the program would not work. I have to do the same in QtCreator, but I don't know how to change that setting in Qt. Could you please suggest how I should approach that? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/MT` is a compiler flag. You can specify flags in your .pro file like this:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MT`

Moreover, you probably want to specify `/MTd` for debug build:

```
Release:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MT
Debug:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MTd
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, for Debug build, I have to specify `/MTd`.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. The answer was already there :D. My bad, I totally missed it. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 5):

In the version of QT 5.5 the variable is QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG and QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE so the new working solution for QT 5.5 is:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MT
```

Answer (score 0):

A qmake configuration is also available for this.

```
CONFIG += thread
```

Answer (score 0):

since `Qt 5`, adding to your `qmake` build script `*.pro` file, a configuration like:

```
CONFIG += static_runtime
```

will cause `qmake` to include the `mkspecs/features/static_runtime.prf` file, which should contain the required configurations, something like below:

```
msvc {
    # -MD becomes -MT, -MDd becomes -MTd
    QMAKE_CFLAGS ~= s,^-MD(d?)$, -MT\1,g
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS ~= s,^-MD(d?)$, -MT\1,g
} else: mingw {
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
}
```

but as advance warning, note that this may cause some link errors, which make an statement like
"`MSVCRT.lib(MSVCRxxx.dll) : error LNK2005: xxx already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(xxx.obj)`", basically because other libraries that you are using are linked with the dynamic CRT library (i.e. they are NOT build with `/MT` or `/MTd` flag, and you would need to rebuild them with the appropriate flag), for more see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728649/error-lnk2005-xxx-already-defined-in-msvcrt-libmsvcr100-dllc-something-libc).