# How to link against static and dynamic libraries at the same time?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, qt-creator, lib

I am using QtCreator for my project, I need to link some libraries dynamically because of license and I have some larger static library available, but I use only a small portion from it. When I try it, I got an error mixing builds.

```
base.lib(base.thread_local_storage.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in Updater.obj
```

I am using msvc2017-64. how to configure the .pro file to achieve this?

Comment: can you post error code?

Comment: base.lib(base.thread_local_storage.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in Updater.obj

Comment: It is platform specific. Different on Linux and on Windows, for example

Answer (score 0):

Your CRT-Bindings are in Mismatch.

Under Project > C/C++ All Options > Runtime Library

You need to change at least one of the libs to MT or MD so there won't be a mismatch anymore.

Here you will find the solution:
[LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in file.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887001/lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary-value-mt-staticrelease-doesn)

If you compile the libs with Visual Studio

Comment: For QtCreator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688079/how-to-change-the-c-runtime-library-setting-in-qtcreator