# ARToolkit Visual Studio- c - error unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func

Tags: c, visual-c++, artoolkit

So, I´m trying to compile one of [ARToolkit](http://artoolkit.org/)´s projects and I´m having some errors:
The first one is related to MSVCRT library. when I igonre it in the Linker ->input I get a lot of errors.

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)
```

the second type of error is somehow related to unresolved external symbols, here is the output:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func referenced in function _printf
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function _printf 
Error   4   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728649/error-lnk2005-xxx-already-defined-in-msvcrt-libmsvcr100-dllc-something-libc) and [this one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-parallel-studio-beta-archived/topic/266345) and it didn´t work

To be specified, I´m running a Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) as a Runtime Library on Release mode.

Comment: You cannot mix code (or libraries) that were compiled with VS2015 with code that was compiled with VS2013.  Or mix /MT and /MD.  Rebuild everything, libraries too.

Comment: That was quick and useful, Thank you @HansPassant it works now

Comment: Hi @HansPassant ! I am trying to compile zlib 1.2.13 for windows and getting "example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func referenced in function _main

[2023-08-08T19:19:44.077Z] example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

[2023-08-08T19:19:44.077Z] NMAKE : fatal error

[2023-08-08T19:19:44.077Z]  U1077: '"c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\bin\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'" How can I check with which vs this zlib was compiled? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio\2019 in my code. Any advice would be appreciated!